# Reset orientation does not work in phone

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I want reset head orientation. I did but that works in PC but not in phone. There is a button called reset. If I click that it should reset the head orientation. It does on PC but not on phone. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rdub80/aframe-gui/master/dist/aframe-gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
  <a-gui-button resetorientation
          id="reset"
          class="clickable"              
          position="-0.038 -1.611 -3.011"
          rotation="-25 0 0"
          width="2.5" height="0.75"
          key-code="80"
          value="Reset"
          font-family="Helvetica"
          background-color="#A04000"           
      >
      </a-gui-button>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
  <a-camera position="0 2 0">
    <a-cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable" ></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my script:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('resetorientation', {
init: function () {
this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('#reset').emit(reset());
  });
 }
});
function reset(){
var x = document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('rotation').x;
var y = document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('rotation').y;
console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
document.querySelector('[camera]').setAttribute('rotation', {x: 0 * x});
document.querySelector('[camera]').setAttribute('rotation', {y: 0 * y});
var a = document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('rotation').x;
var b = document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('rotation').y;
console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: The camera constantly update the view based on the rotation of the phone. So yes reset works BUT right after resetting the new values of rotations get applied again.

Comment: @Utopiah Is there any way to reset camera on phone? Like if I click reset button it will reset and stay for 3 sec. Any way?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get into the `look-controls` and manually add an offset to the x-y-z rotations it gets from the gyroscope.

---

A workaround making sense with only the yaw (y) value, would be wrapping the camera in an entity, and when you click `reset`, you rotate the wrappers yaw.

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bscdku9k/9/).

Comment: Can you give an example. it's better to understand. please.

Comment: yes. It's correct. I understand. But is this work on phone also?

Comment: the gyroscope modifies the `<a-camera>` only, so there shouldn't be any contraindications for it to work on a phone

Comment: how come ? its working on my phone: http://mileskipls.pl/test/phonerot/ once i click the cylinder i get reorientated to 0 0 0

Comment: https://www.learning.oddly.co/vrdev 
check this one. it does not work on phones. But it works on PC. 
When you go to that url wait for some sec. there is a reset button. click that.

Comment: Even after resetting the camera rotation it does not go down. Why?

Comment: because you're rotating the camera - not the wrapper - even the logs say that it goes to 0 0 0. Is my example website working for you ? Btw you change rotation.y = 0*-rotation.y, why there's a zero ?

Comment: Yes there is Zero. And I did as like you did. What's the bug? Any solution for that?

Comment: i'm doing `rotation.y = -rotation.y;` not `rotation.y = 0*-rotation.y;
`. It looks like You rotate the camera with something else than the component (since it's not setting anything for the camera)

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/indigo-crime?path=index.html:15:22
check this. I did like this. But it does not work properly.

Comment: Now. just check this link again. https://www.learning.oddly.co/vrdev
I put `rotation.y = -rotation.y`

Comment: @Sabbir33 the glitch works properly, it resets the yaw (y) and you can still look up / down. As is said, the workaround should only change the yaw of the camera

Comment: https://www.learning.oddly.co/vrdev
In this link I used same like you. After that it works. But after clicking twice it's not moving down. What can be the reason?

Comment: I just now got the error. 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/indigo-crime?path=index.html:6:49 in this we used A-Frame 0.8.0. It works fine. But if you change it to 0.7.1 it won't work. I have tested it. I am using 0.7.1. That's the problem. So can I do for this?